# What is optimal data flow between PHP backend and Vue frontend

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I am wondering, what would be the best setup of data flow from PHP (database) to fronted Javascript rendering, lets say VueJS.

My first idea is, that will provide data attribute with JSON data to HTML element - div, which Vue instance will be mounted on.

I dont want to create REST API and load data via AJAX HTTP requests from Vue.

```php
# PHP part
echo '<div id="myId" data-my-data="{h1:\"My heading\"}"></div>';
```

```js
// Javascript part
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import App from './MyApp.vue';

const el = document.querySelector('#myId');

new Vue({
    el,
    render: h => h(App, {
        props: {
            myData: JSON.parse(el.dataset.myData),
        },
    }),
});
```

What do you think, is it ok or is there any other option except REST?

**Update:**
Main purpose is that my App will handle complex - multi-step Forms with some complex fields, which I would like to create as reusable components.

App will validate forms via AJAX (to prevent re-rendering page), on success redirect to success page.

My infrastructure would be, that PHP will prepare data, render main layout with assets (JS + CSS) and DIV with data atributes for Vue App.

Comment: What do you mean by REST?

Comment: If you're going to hard code the data into the elements `data`-attributes, why not just render the HTML like you want it directly instead?

Comment: @Pointy By REST I ment AJAX request to REST API.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah, this I can, but I like idea of Javascript reactive rendering . How could I read data in Vue instance when I render HTML in PHP, only with data attributes or global variables, which I do not like at all

Comment: Are you trying to initializing Vue.js data from the server side (without ajax)? [Link](https://dev.to/dopitz/initializing-vuejs-data-from-the-server-side-4np)

Comment: _"but I like idea of Javascript reactive rendering"_ - Why? There's no reason for that if you're just using static data. Libraries like Vue etc solves the issue with using dynamic data, which you aren't. That's just adding an extra layer of complexity that's totally pointless. There's also an extra performance cost.

Comment: @odan yes, exactly.. The initial state of Vue App

Comment: @MagnusEriksson because I would like to make not trivial front end app, where Vannila JS would be make it very difficult. I think its not another layer, its just PHP rendering layer (lets say Twig) transformed (replaced by) into reactive javascript

Comment: If you update your question to include what you're app suppose to do and what you would be using vue for (more than just render data put in data-attributes), we might be able to come up with some good suggestions, but currently, it just seems like you're trying to use vue for the sake of using vue, not because it actually is a good tool for what you're doing.

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to pre-render html on the server, e.g. for a better SEO score. I have written a blog post about this topic: [Read more](https://dev.to/dopitz/initializing-vuejs-data-from-the-server-side-4np). PS: Like Magnus E. said, don't use Vue just for the sake of using Vue. Choose the right tool for the job.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson mainly I suppose to create App which will handle forms. There are cases, when I will have to manage multi-step forms where fields can depend on other fields or create complex field types. Thats why my first vision was that I could built reusable components.

Comment: @odan I've read your article. What I dont like is that you use `Vue.prototype.initData` which can be tricky, when you have multiple instances of Vue. Might be I am wrong, havent tested it... Anyways, your article is very close to my idea. I would like to have PHP generated layout with assets management and so on, but content handling via Vue